# Split cell at last space excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to split a value inside a cell at the last space. For example, I want `Abbey Road 4` split to `Abbey Road` and `4`

I need this to be done with VBA, not a Formula, as I need to delete the original Column afterwards.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What have you tried?  Please post any attempt.  SO is great to help find where code needs help, but is not a website to do the work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at INSTRREV to find the last occurrence of a string within a string.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hsxyczeb(v=vs.84).aspx

```
Sub Test()

    SplitText ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A11")

End Sub

Sub SplitText(SrcRange As Range)

    Dim rCell As Range

    For Each rCell In SrcRange.Cells
        rCell.Offset(, 1) = Left(rCell, InStrRev(rCell, " ") - 1)
        rCell.Offset(, 2) = Mid(rCell, InStrRev(rCell, " ") + 1)
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice use of `InStrRev`, I forget about that one.

Comment: @Bond - good point.  I'll update the code to reflect that.  **Edit:**  Bond removed his comment - code originally had LEN(rcell) at end of MID statement.  This isn't required.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation on the answer from Darren Bartrup-Cook ...

Assume cell A2 has the text `Some text with spaces` in it, below will put `Some text with` in C2 and `spaces` in D2

```
'Get text from A2
theText = Cells(2, 1).Value

'Get text to the left of last space
newTextLeft = Left(theText, InStrRev(theText, " ") - 1)
Cells(2, 3).Value = newTextLeft

'Get text to right of last space
newTextRight = Mid(theText, InStrRev(theText, " ") + 1)
Cells(2, 4).Value = newTextRight
```